# PHP inside jQuery (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using a jQuery script for a Wordpress page and wanted to get some variable value but is not working:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.wpcs_curr_link').click(function () {
      window.location.href = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '?currency=' + jQuery(this).data('curr') + '#rates-default'; 
    });
  });
<?php 
  global $WPCS;
  $curr =  $WPCS->current_currency;
?>
   jQuery('a [data-curr="'+<?php echo $curr ?>+'"]').addClass( "currency_selected" );
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I can not use $ as well, as it gives error. Any workaround to this?

Comment: What error? This code seems right to me. So, I am interested in knowing exactly what error is occurring.

Comment: I am using this piece of code in the custom script. The error is:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
It's showing error for the <?php

Comment: Is this error a JavaScript error - i.e., occurs in the browser?

Comment: In Console and the button does not work.

Comment: Wow, it seems that PHP didn't recognize the '<?php'. That seems wrong to me.

Comment: Try using <?php echo "jQuery('a [data-curr=\"$curr\"]').addClass( \"currency_selected\" );"; ?>

Comment: I think the error is shown for the 
<?php 
global $WPCS; 
$curr =  $WPCS->current_currency;
?>

Comment: I will have to write an answer as it will not fit as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `$` with jQuery and word press you need to do the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  //Now, you can do something like:
$("#someInput").val();
});
```

As for the other problem, you can't put PHP directly in a page, you have to use a template and then base the page on that template. There are however plugins that allow you to add PHP wherever you need it. All that being said, you might be using the wrong approach. You should generally avoid using PHP inside of JavaScript/jQuery if you can, it makes your code harder to maintain.

Comment: Thank you. Okey, the only thing I am trying to achieve is to add the class on a specific button which is clicked recently. OR the button to be selected when clicked.

Answer (score -1):

Following things might help you:

- You need to add jQuery code inside of jQuery DOM ready method, so that browser can handle it properly after loading the required contents such as jQuery library.
- You don't need to add PHP code like as JS variable. You can change your code to:

  ```
  jQuery("a [data-curr='<?php echo $curr ?>']").addClass( "currency_selected" );
  ```
- You need to add PHP code in a PHP template file related to that page like 'page.php' or something else. You just cannot add PHP code into JS file or in any admin panel input section.
- And finally, try to avoid using PHP inside of JS, make it manageable in other way.

You can put more details about your problem like 'in which template file you are adding this code or what is the front-end page/URL'

Comment: Well, I am adding that piece of code in custom JS. The definition <?php global $WPCS; $curr = $WPCS->current_currency; ?> gives an error. The error is: 1
(index):152 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
on Console.

Comment: As I said, if you add PHP code inside of JS file, that shouldn't be ok.